# Incomprehensible vs Unintelligible

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, adjectives

I'm having a hard time fathoming the difference between *incomprehensible* and *unintelligible*.

After some research, I assume that

> **incomprehensible** would be used to express the inability to understand a problem and finding a solution for it or to fathom a process.

whilst

> **unintelligible** rather emphasizes that a sound or writing is difficult to grasp or understand, for example due to noise or crabbed handwriting.

Is this correct?

Comment: They are largely unrelated. Intelligibility goes before comprehensibility. If you can read it but not understand it, it's *incomprehensible;* if you can't read it in the first place, it's *unintelligible*. HTH.

Comment: I would not like to confuse you but what is unintelligible may also be said to be incomprehensible in a broader sense.

Comment: What @Kris said. Both terms are often used interchangeably, but if I were ["eavesdropping,"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eavesdrop) I'd normally say what I heard was *unintelligible* if I couldn't hear all the words properly, or it included slang/jargon I wasn't familiar with. If I could hear the words, but simply couldn't understand the *concepts* being discussed, I'd be more likely to use *incomprehensible*.

Comment: An overly noisy signal is unintelligble. A computer generated proof of the four color theorem may well be Incomprehensible.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger Fairly sure a human-generated proof of the four-colour theorem would be equally incomprehensible to me…

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way to try to distinguish between these two terms is to check their definitions in one or more good dictionaries. Here are their definitions in *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, fifth edition (2011):

> **incomprehensible** *adj*. **1a.** Difficult or impossible to understand or comprehend; unintelligible: *incomprehensible jargon*. **b.** Impossible to know or fathom: *incomprehensible mysteries*. **2.** *Archaic* Having no limits; boundless.
>
> ...
>
> **unintelligible** *adj*. Difficult or impossible to understand or comprehend; incomprehensible: *unintelligible remarks*; *an unintelligible prose passage*.

According to *AHDEL*, then, there is no difference between the meaning of *unintelligible* and meaning **1a** of *incomprehensible*; but *incomprehensible* also has the meaning "unknowable or unfathomable," which *unintelligible* does not.

*Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (2003) offers this definition for *incomprehensible*:

> **incomprehensible** *adj* (14c) **1** *archaic* **:** having or subject to no limits **2 :** impossible to to comprehend : UNINTELLIGIBLE {*incomprehensible* instructions}

Regrettably, the *Eleventh Collegiate* doesn't provide a definition for *unintelligible*, even though in normal practice its use of all caps in a single-word definition signals that the reader should refer to the entry for the word thus capitalized to find the full definition of that word.

The *Eleventh Collegiate* does have an entry for *intelligible*—and presumably its omission of a definition for *unintelligible* indicates that MW views the definition of *unintelligible* as boiling down to "not intelligible." Here at any rate is the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s entry for *intelligible*:

> **intelligible** *adj* (14c) **1 :** apprehensible by the intellect only **2 :** capable of being understood or comprehended {jargon *intelligible* only to the initiated}

Unfortunately, the negative of definition **1** above is a bad match for the actual meaning of *unintelligible* because it suggests that something that is apprehensible by the senses as well as by the intellect—and therefore not "apprehensible to the intellect **only**"—might properly be characterized as "not intelligible," and therefore as "unintelligible." This is clearly a false line of reasoning, however, occasioned by the *Eleventh Collegiate*'s sloppy treatment of *unintelligible*.

What MW really intends to offer as the definition of *unintelligible*, I think, is "not capable of being understood or comprehended"—that is, the negative of definition **2** above.

Merriam-Webster's full-size *Webster's Third New International Dictionary* 1986) does a much better job of identifying the different meanings of the two words:

> **incomprehensible** *adj* **1** *archaic* **:** having or subject to no limits : ILLIMITABLE [citation from Richard Hooker omitted] **2 a :** impossible to comprehend : lying above or beyond the human mind {the *incomprehensible* mysteries of creation} **b :** being beyond the powers of comprehension of a particular mind : UNINTELLIGIBLE {an incomprehensible subject to him} **c :** being beyond ordinary comprehension : UNFATHOMABLE {*incomprehensible* moods} {a whimsical *incomprehensible* person} **3** *obs* **:** impossible to catch or hold
>
> ...
>
> **unintelligible** *adj* **:** not intelligible : difficult to comprehend : OBSCURE

It thus appears that the *Third New International*, like *AHDEL*, recognizes that *unintelligible* and *incomprehensible* share a meaning (definition **2b** in the *Third New International*) but that *incomprehensible* has a much wider range of possible meanings. Especially interesting is the *Third New International*'s observation that *unintelligible* applies to particular minds, whereas *incomprehensible* may refer to such minds or to the human mind more generally.

---

***Conclusion***

To a considerable extent, the words *incomprehensible* and *unintelligible* have overlapping meanings; and a reader who consults *Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary* (for example) in hopes of reading a lucid explanation of how they differ is likely to be disappointed. But other dictionaries suggest that the main difference between the two words is that, while *unintelligible* is essentially interchangeable with *incomprehensible* in the sense of "difficult or impossible to for a particular mind under particular circumstances to understand," *incomprehensible* may also convey a more abstract or generalized notion that the thing so characterized is beyond human understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Sven's answer evidences the extensive overlap in the meanings of the two words, and that without explicit usage sections which address the difference, dictionaries can do as much or more to tangle rather than untangle the two words.

It may add value then to read about the words' particular historical usages in various academic and professional fields.

For example, 'comprehension' is [conceived differently in fields such as logic, language learning, and mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehension), and 'intelligibility' is [conceived differently in fields of philosophy, linguistics, and communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intelligibility).

Comment: +1 This is a very useful point to bear in mind whenever discussions of "what [particular] words mean" arise.